# Use PDF FormFields in enveloppe

Tags: docusignapi

I need to use PdfFormField in an enveloppe, with 2 signers.
I use a dummy pdf file with only 1 field, but I can't get DocuSign to fill it.

Is there any special way to address it ?
Can you tell me what is wrong in my json ?

Here is the json sent :

```
{
    "emailSubject": "Dummy",
    "status": "sent",
    "documents": [
        {
            "documentId": "1",
            "name": "dummy.pdf",
            "documentBase64": "...",
            "transformPdfFields": "true",
            "recipients": {
                "signers": [
                    {
                        "recipientId": "1",
                        "tabs": {
                            "textTabs": [
                                {
                                    "documentId": "1",
                                    "pageNumber": "1",
                                    "recipientId": "1",
                                    "tabLabel": "acq-civ",
                                    "value": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
                                    "required": "true"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "recipientId": "2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [
            {
                "recipientId": "1",
                "roleName": "buyer",
                "firstname": "Firstname",
                "lastname": "Lastname",
                "name": "Full Name",
                "email": "email@gmail.com",
                "routingOrder": 1
            },
            {
                "recipientId": "2",
                "roleName": "owner",
                "name": "Full Name2",
                "email": "email2@gmail.com",
                "routingOrder": 2
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to do it using compositeTemplates.  Simple documents structure doesn't allow form field manipulation after transformation